# Exception in defer callback: Error: No uiManager configured on Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I guess the better question here is more general: how do I debug errors for deployed apps? Does Meteor have commands/logs I can look at? I'm really not sure where to begin because everything works fine locally.

I'm getting this error in the browser console when I try to view the Meteor app I deployed to *.meteor.com. Output is a blank screen, but locally, the same code results in no errors and output is normal.

Has anyone seen this before? There's [a thread](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/issues/53&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHT4p22X-WngkKomrJx2VXez6VGPg) connecting this to accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 but I'm not using that.

For reference, I'm using Meteor 0.8.1.3, blaze-layout 0.2.4, iron-router 0.7.1, and accounts-entry 0.7.3.

EDIT: looking at `meteor logs` right now but nothing constructive so far.

Comment: yes I am have the exact same issue so suggest that there may have been an update to iron-router or meteor today that broke this.

Comment: Alex, in my case, it wasn't Meteor at all...the reference to 'Router' was misleading. Tinymce, a jQuery package I'm using, was actually the problem. I only found out by clicking the link to the source from the error in the console and scrolling around. 

Look around your source in the browser to see if you find anything similar.

Comment: I ended up resetting and reinstalling everything and this fixed it...

Comment: @AlexWebster--do you mean you uninstalled and reinstalled all your packages and then redeployed? I'm having this exact problem and just removing and adding iron-router didn't fix it.

Comment: @charliemagee Added a solution that worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using meteorite? Try adding blaze-layout:

```
mrt add blaze-layout
```

And check in `.meteor/packages` that it loads **after** iron-router.

Then deploy as usual to *.meteor.com

Comment: Although this isn't the approach that solved my problem, I'll mark as solved since there are no other answers. Thanks @SDude.

Comment: @m52go : what was your approach?

Comment: @Diskdrive check my comment on the original question. Basically, there was an error buried in the console coming from a plug-in I was using called Tinymce. It wasn't related to Meteor at all.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue, in same places (prod but not dev). Running `mrt update` and `meteor update` fixed it for me.

Comment: I ran into this error (No uiManager configured on Router) when I ran `meteor update` without running `mrt update`. Running `mrt update` fixed that for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue after updating to the latest meteor with:

```
$ sudo meteor update
```

Read through several posts, and found my issue was caused by not running the update through Meteorite:

```
$ sudo mrt update
```

This fixed the slew of errors I encountered.

Also, I had to *remove* the package blaze-layout, which I had manually added through mrt as suggested above, because it caused a recursive dependency with with iron-layout.